# Create missing or mismatch data query from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched high and low and have spent several days trying different combinations of joins to no avail so would welcome the collective advice please.  I have created multiple scenarios of joins and "with" statements and can't help i'm missing an obvious solution.

**Background.**

By way of example we have a table with columns similar to :-

```
BuySideTradeDate | BuySideContract | BuySidePrice | BuySideQuantity | SellSideTradeDate | SellSideContract | SellSidePrice | SellSideQuantity
```

This is an example table but the concept is the same. The purpose of this table is to store data from both an internal system and an external system to compare any differences or any missing data.  For this example, we will assume there is one trade per day executed. There will be a separate row for each trade issue, for example :-

1. We might have a trade done on the buy side that's missing from the
   sell side (there will only be one row in the table for this trade
   with only the buy info completed).
2. Conversely, we might have a trade done on the sell side missing from
   the buy side (there will only be one row in the table for this trade
   with only the sell info completed).
3. We may have a trade done on the sell side that exists on the buy
   side but the price may be different (there will two rows in the
   table with corresponding columns populated).

**Challenge**

We need to create a query to do two things; Firstly to "matche" the same Contract (on both buy and sell sides) and Trade date on both sides (if two matching rows exist) and then also, if there are no matches, we need to simply return that single row (regardless of whether it's the buy side or the sell side is populated).  If there is a match of the contract and trade date we need to combine those two rows into one!

Essentially this then provides data for a report which is used to either discover missing trades from either side or mismatched trades.

Example input data (thank you for the prompt @Radim) (sorry formatting is poor)

```
BuySideTradeDate    BuySideContract BuySidePrice    BuySideQuantity SellSideTradeDate   SellSideContract    SellSidePrice   SellSideQuantity

10/04/2018  Sugar   100 10              
15/04/2018  Sugar   101 12              
16/04/2018  Coffee  200 10              
20/04/2018  Corn    300 11              
25/04/2018  Corn    305 15              
                               10/04/2018   Sugar   100.5   10
                               15/04/2018   Sugar   101     11
                               16/04/2018   Coffee  201     10
                               26/04/2018   Oil     1000    1

Expected Output

10/04/2018  Sugar   100 10  10/04/2018  Sugar   100.5   10 (contract/date/quantity match but price do not)
15/04/2018  Sugar   101 12  15/04/2018  Sugar   101     11 (contract/date/price match but quantity does not)
16/04/2018  Coffee  200 10  16/04/2018  Coffee  201     10 (contract/date/quantity match but price does not)
20/04/2018  Corn    300 11 (missing from sell side)             
25/04/2018  Corn    305 15 (missing from sell side)
                            26/04/2018  Oil     1000    1 (missing from buy side)
```

I suspect this is a combination of sub queries and joins but is there a simpler way that I am missing!

Really very much appreciate any input!

Shout if I have been too ambiguous or you need further clarity.

Thanks.

Comment: Example data and expected result would be a plus

Comment: kk, thank you - will pull some data together - brb

Comment: @RadimBača Data added - ty

Answer (score 0):

I create two tables: `buy_side` and `sell_side`.

```
create table #buy_side (
    foo varchar(5) null
  , bar int null
  , san int null
);

create table #sell_side (
    foo varchar(5) null
  , bar int null
  , san int null
);
```

I add values to each table:

```
INSERT INTO #buy_side (foo, bar, san)
VALUES ('XYZ', 3, 5)
     , ('ABC', 11, 8)
     , ('XYP', 2, 5)

INSERT INTO #sell_side (foo, bar, san)
VALUES ('XYP', 8, 9)
     , ('ABC', 11, 8)
     , ('XYZ', 6, 4)
```

There is only one value matching between the two tables: ('ABC', 11, 8).

```
--In both buy and sell side
select * 
from #buy_side
INTERSECT
select * 
from #sell_side

--In buy side but not sell side
select * 
from #buy_side
EXCEPT
select * 
from #sell_side

--In sell side but not buy side
select * 
from #sell_side
EXCEPT
select * 
from #buy_side
```

Here are the results when I run these...

[image]

As long as the schema between the two tables (or relations, if selecting a subset of a table) matches, this should work.

**UPDATE**

Clarifying that last comment. Let's say all your data is in the same table. You're distinguishing a buy from a sell with a flag; for this example we'll say `category`. You'd select the buy records. You'd select the sell records. Then you'd `intersect` or `except` the select statements.

```
create table #trade (
    foo varchar(5) null
  , bar int null
  , san int null
  , category varchar(max) null
);

INSERT INTO #trade (foo, bar, san, category)
VALUES ('XYZ', 3, 5, 'buy')
     , ('ABC', 11, 8, 'buy')
     , ('XYP', 2, 5, 'buy')
     , ('XYP', 8, 9, 'sell')
     , ('ABC', 11, 8, 'sell')
     , ('XYZ', 6, 4, 'sell')

SELECT foo, bar, san
FROM #trade
WHERE category = 'sell'
INTERSECT
SELECT foo, bar, san
FROM #trade
WHERE category = 'buy'

SELECT foo, bar, san
FROM #trade
WHERE category = 'sell'
EXCEPT
SELECT foo, bar, san
FROM #trade
WHERE category = 'buy'

SELECT foo, bar, san
FROM #trade
WHERE category = 'buy'
EXCEPT
SELECT foo, bar, san
FROM #trade
WHERE category = 'sell'
```

I'm using temp tables here because it makes creating the example easier (I don't have to clean-up after). You can use whatever tables you'd like.

Comment: We only have one table with the data (either the sell or buy side is ever populated).

Are you suggesting we create virtual/temp tables and extract the data on the fly?

Comment: No, I'm not. What you'd do in that case (I'm going to simplify a bit), is select the datasets and compare them. I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Start by joining the table to itself (using two different aliases). Something like:

```
SELECT BuySide.BuySidePrice,
  BuySide.BuySideQuantity,
  SellSide.SellSidePrice,
  SellSide.SellSideQuantity
FROM MyTable BuySide
  LEFT JOIN MyTable SellSide ON BuySide.BuySideTradeDate=SellSide.SellSideTradeDate AND BuySide.BuySideContract=SellSide.SellSideContract
```

This is by far not complete but it is a first step to get you where you need to go. I am also not sure if you wanted to match just dates or also contracts; this one compares both but you can easily modify it to match just dates.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `FULL JOIN`. This allows for `NULL` values on either side of the join to remain, while also combining the rows of "matched" values across the join.

example:

```
SELECT BuySide.TradeDate, SellSide.TradeDate, etc...
FROM TBL_BuySide BuySide
FULL JOIN TBL_SellSide SellSide ON BuySide.TradeDate = SellSide.TradeDate
                                   AND BuySide.Contract = SellSide.Contract
```

As a note, this would produce duplicates if two lines within either the buy or sell sides have same trade date and contract.

Comment: I believe that normal `INNER JOIN` is needed in this case

Comment: @RadimBača his expected output has data which is missing from both the buy and sell sides. If you use an `INNER JOIN` you would lose those rows and would be left with only the first three and not all 6 that he is wanting.

Comment: @rdbradshaw You are correct, that's exactly what happens and is not the desired result.  Just digesting the responses here.  Thank you.

Comment: It's almost as if I need to do a "LEFT OUTER" join (which will give me the missing sells) AND a "RIGHT OUTER" join (which will give me the missing buys) and then an INNER join which will give me the "mismatches"

So perhaps, this consists of three subqueries???

Comment: @rdbradshaw We only have one table, not the tbl_sellside and tbl_buyside you use in your sample code.